# Relative model reference?

Tags: angularjs

I'm writing a few components for a form, these will be included (via Grails `<g:include>` tags) in multiple places (a registration page, and an account page). The way Angular works, I have to specify the form name in order to get a reference to a particular field. For example:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input ng-model="username"/>
  {{myForm.username}} -- right here
</form>
```

In the example above, I must use `myForm` in order to access `username`. This will not work when using the same field in multiple forms, as the form name will change.

Is there a way to access the field relatively, or maybe figure out the enclosing form name and inject that?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to reference your form's name. Just bind it to a property on your controller's `$scope` and you should be good to go. Doing it this way, you won't have to care what your form name is, only that the controller has the property you need.

```
<form ng-controller="yourController">
  <input ng-model="username"/>
  {{ username }}
</form>

angular.controller('yourController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.username = 'keanu reeves';
}]);
```

[Here's a code pen.](http://codepen.io/yatrix/pen/PNxZWL?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use some sort of dynamic form name code.  e.g.

```
<div ng-repeat="myForm in forms">
    <form name="myForm{{$index}}">
      <input ng-model="myForm.username"/>
      {{myForm.username}} -- right here
    </form>
</div>
```

Although it's difficult to solve your exact problem without example code.  Create a plunker or codepen that we can analyze.

Comment: There is only one form (per page), the form name is depending on the page. The included field needs to know the form name to use.